# In Salesforce- Invalid id: Invalid Field defined in MetadataLine number

Tags: salesforce, metadata, apex

I'm using Platform event (configured metadata with event on fields) to pull records that got update from one object to another object , just to keep updates on my tracker. When tested to reproduce, with same action the error is not logged.

Getting this error logged=> Invalid id: Invalid Field defined in MetadataLine number

Any suggestions / solutions would be much appreciated

On updating fields on Obj1 should reflect/update on Obj2.
This is working properly, updates are showing up in Obj2.

But the issue is error is also getting logged=> Invalid id: Invalid Field defined in MetadataLine number.

Created a custom meteadata & FLow for using it as generic platform event, where it gets triggered when one of the field is updated in Obj1 and this will update on Obj2.